# @Inject and @Autowired not working whereas injecting with setter works

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I used `@Autowired` hundreds of time but today I don't get it, neither `@Autowired` nor `@Inject` work in a new project I just created, I get the famous error

> Invalid property 'jdbcTemplate' of bean class [com.xxx.SomeDAO]: Bean
>   property 'jdbcTemplate' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

When I add a setter for `jdbcTemplate` in `SomeDAO`, it works...

applicationContext.xml:

```
...
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="com.xxx.SomeDAO" class="com.xxx.SomeDAO">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
...
```

SomeDAO.java:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import javax.inject.Inject;
//import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class SomeDAO {

    @Inject // Doesn't work
    //@Autowired // Doesn't work either
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    ...

    /* Works if I add this setter
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }*/
}
```

What could prevent the injection through the annotation? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it without the property element in the applicationContext.xml? Maybe it is having a conflict with that. I don't combine annotations and xml.

Comment: There is no property, there is only a field. The whole point of using `@Autowired` or the likes is that you don't need to specify the dependencies in XML any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use field-injection when the bean is created with the XML-context the way you have provided it. Your class is not part of any *component-scanning* and therefore the annotations does not kick in. Therefore, I can see at least the following options:

**1. Use a setter as per your example and remove the `@Inject`**

This is the simplest approach since you got the code and XML prepared. However, this means that your DAO must expose an unnecessary setter-method.

**2. Use a constructor that sets your `jdbcTemplate` field**

This is according to me a better alternative but it means that you need to rewrite the XML like this:

```
<bean id="com.xxx.SomeDAO" class="com.xxx.SomeDAO">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

And, your constructor like this:

```
public class SomeDAO {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public SomeDAO(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

**3. Add component-scanning and use @Autowired (or @Inject)**

I think that this is the best approach if you fully want to utilize the beauty of Spring's dependency injection capabilities. Add the following to your XML-context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx"/>
```

And then the code you previously provided should work. However, you should probably consider avoiding field-injection in favour of constructor-injection. The [opinions differ on this matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218868/setter-injection-vs-constructor-injection) but I find the code harder to test when field-injection is used.

Constructor injection looks like this:

```
// The component scanner will find this annotation and create 
// the bean (and inject the dependencies)
@Component
public class SomeDAO {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired // enables constructor-injection
    public SomeDAO(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

I personally prefer alternative #3 since it is clean, Java-based (practically no XML required) which also means that it is *refactoring friendly*, there is no field *magic* happening and the constructor-based approach makes the code testable and does not expose any unnecessary setter-methods.

A good starting point to learn more about this is the excellent [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html). There you can find a great explanation for all of the above!

Comment: I messed up the config indeed, the context:component-scan was missing. I'll look into the constructor injection, it may be useful sometimes.