# Spring inject without autowire annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, autowired

I find some answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218921/2754014 about Dependency Injection. There isn't any annotation like `@Autowired`, `@Inject` or `@Resource`. let's assume that there isn't any XML configuration for this example `TwoInjectionStyles` bean (except simple `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />`.

Is it correct to inject without specify annotation?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From Spring 4.3 annotations are not required for constructor injection.

```
public class MovieRecommender {

    private CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao;

    private MovieCatalog movieCatalog;

    //@Autowired - no longer necessary
    public MovieRecommender(CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao) {
        this.customerPreferenceDao = customerPreferenceDao;
    }

    @Autowired 
    public setMovieCatalog(MovieCatalog movieCatalog) {
        this.movieCatalog = movieCatalog;
    }
}
```

But you still need `@Autowired` for setter injection. I checked a moment ago with `Spring Boot 1.5.7` (using `Spring  4.3.11`) and when I removed `@Autowired` then bean was not injected.

Comment: So this anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218921/2754014 is not correct?

Comment: Unless I missed something,  won't work. So your're right, without any xml configuration this answer is incorrect.

Comment: This official example is kind of misleading me. I thought setter injection would work without @Autowired if it has a no-arg constructor.  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-setter-injection

Answer (score 14):

Yes, example is correct (starting from Spring 4.3 release). According to the documentation ([this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) for ex), if a bean has **single** constructor, `@Autowired` annotation can be omitted.

But there are several nuances:

**1.** When single constructor is present and setter is marked with `@Autowired` annotation, than both constructor & setter injection will be performed one after another:

```
@Component
public class TwoInjectionStyles {
    private Foo foo;

    public TwoInjectionStyles(Foo f) {
        this.foo = f; //Called firstly
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setFoo(Foo f) { 
        this.foo = f; //Called secondly
    }
}
```

**2.** At the other hand, if there is no `@Autowire` at all (as in your [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218921/2754014)), than `f` object will be injected once via constructor, and setter can be used in it's common way without any injections.