# What are the advantages of constructor autowiring over normal autowiring or property autowiring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there any specific advantages for constructor autowiring over property autowiring ... Or normal one .?  Superior forcing team to use constructor autowiring in spring boot .. is there any specific advantages for it . Pros and cons of both type of autowiring

Comment: One of them is that when testing, doing a mock over a constructor is easy, but over properties it's a little bit hard

Comment: Rule of thumb: stick to constructor injection. Why? A constructor specifies the required dependencies of the class being instantiated. With setter/field injection on the other hand, you always have to look them up (by looking at the source code). You may run into troubles (eg NPE's) because an instance misses some required dependencies. Have a look at http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/

Comment: Thanks for your response .. will there any con for using constructor autowiring ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain why constructor inject is better than other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218868/explain-why-constructor-inject-is-better-than-other-options)

Comment: @benny none that I am aware of. It actually shields you from wiring up cyclic dependencies (which is not the case for setter/field injection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor autowiring has advantages in that you can make the wired in fields final (particularly useful if your bean will be called from multiple threads as threadsafety is easier to analyse with finals). And you can ensure that the bean is always constructed in a valid way (although you can always implement `InitializingBean` and use the `afterPropertiesSet` method to achieve the same if you're wiring in properties).

Wiring properties can be better if you have many fields as it avoids having very many arguments in your constructor, and wiring by name is less prone to mixing up the variables if you're using xml (consider a constructor with many arguments all of one type - it would be easy to wire in the wrong variable). Wiring properties also makes it easier to have optional properties - optional properties with constructor wiring would require multiple constructors, which can quickly get complicated.

In summary, both approaches have their pros and cons - we usually use property wiring unless there's a particular reason we should use constructor wiring.

Comment: disagree with `Wiring properties can be better if you have many fields...`. this is usually a sign of a code smell as the class might have too many responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor wiring is also helpful in writing bugfree code. If you wire dependencies through constructor autowiring, you would be able to easily mock them using mocking frameworks, and inject them through the constructor.

Specifically, Mockito fails silently while mocking dependencies, and if you haven't used constructor autowiring it becomes hard to debug where your code is breaking.

If you follow TDD for writing big enterprise applications, constructor autowiring is helpful.